# How to correctly normalize data set in to tables?

Tags: mysql, normalization

I have a table where first column refers user name other columns refer each subjects that student does and their skill level for each subjects. These subjects are belong to several main subjects streams such as Mathematics, Art and etc.

I normalize the data in to following tables.

Subject_Stream

```
id Main_Stream Subject
1 Math pure-maths

2 Math applied-maths

3 Art Dancing

4 Art Music
```

Student_table

```
id name subject skill_level
1 xxx Music 5
2 xxx Pur-math 4
3 xxx Applied-math 1
4 yyy Music 3



select subjects, skill_level where usename="xxx" order by Desc
```

I can use a similar query to get subjects and their skill level for any given student.

Apart from, this I need to select students when I select any subject or collection of subjects that do.And print their Name, subjects, skill level in descending order.

Here any student can do different subjects in different  streams too.

But I can't easily get this result from my existing tables. How to do this correctly?
Do I need to improve database schema?

Answer (score 1):

First I want to suggest two small improvement for your table structure to better normalize the data. Your table `Student_table` would be slighly better organized if

1. instead of `name` you reference the user_id from your studends-table (that means the name of the student is only present in your studends-table - remember, names can change, p.e. marriage) and
2. instead of the name of the `subject` you reference the id of the subject - therefore the name of the subject is only present in your table `Subject_Stream`.

Your table `Student_table` would then look something like this:

```
id user_id subject_id skill_level
--------------------------------
1  1       4          5
2  1       1          4
3  1       2          1
4  2       4          3
```

Based on this you should be able to get every query you describe. For specifics please update your question and add some examples how your desired results look like, then I'll look into it and give you a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

> Apart from, this I need to select students when I select any subject
>   or collection of subjects that do. And print their Name, subjects,
>   skill level in descending order.

For a single subject . . .

```
select name, subject, skill_level
from Student_table
where subject = 'your subject name'
order by skill_level desc, name asc
```

For multiple subjects . . .

```
select name, subject, skill_level
from Student_table
where subject = 'some subject name'
   or subject = 'some other subject name'
order by skill_level desc, name asc
```

There are other ways to express this kind of query, but I think multiple OR clauses is the easiest to understand at first.

To select by stream (Math, in this case) . . .

```
select Student_table.name
     , Student_table.subject
     , Student_table.skill_level
     , subject_stream.main_stream
from Student_table
inner join subject_stream
        on subject_stream.subject = student_table.subject
where subject_stream.main_stream = 'Math'
order by Student_table.skill_level desc, name asc
```